# mouse leave is triggered wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm stucked for 2 hours trying to find why in the console I can see "mouse leave" when I mouse over the `element` that's inside `sidebar`. The thing is that **only If I enter the mouse from the top** I can see the log in the console. **Chrome 37.0.2062.120 m (64-bit)**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css">
 <style type="text/css">
  * { margin:0; padding:0; }
  html,body{ height:100%; }
  #sidebar{ position: relative; width:200px; height:400px; background:green; overflow: hidden;}
  .elementToScroll { float:left; width:100%; }
 </style>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('.element').on('mouseleave', function(){
    console.log("mouse leave");
   });
  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="sidebar">
  <div class="element">
   <p style="background-color:red;"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium fugit dolores autem tempora harum veniam, eos, perferendis rerum quaerat ea, vitae incidunt rem eaque animi culpa deleniti dignissimos molestias quae. </p>
   <p style="background-color:yellow;"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium fugit dolores autem tempora harum veniam, eos, perferendis rerum quaerat ea, vitae incidunt rem eaque animi culpa deleniti dignissimos molestias quae. </p>
   <p style="background-color:orange;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium fugit dolores autem tempora harum veniam, eos, perferendis rerum quaerat ea, vitae incidunt rem eaque animi culpa deleniti dignissimos molestias quae.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium fugit dolores autem tempora harum veniam, eos, perferendis rerum quaerat ea, vitae incidunt rem eaque animi culpa deleniti dignissimos molestias quae.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium fugit dolores autem tempora harum veniam, eos, perferendis rerum quaerat ea, vitae incidunt rem eaque animi culpa deleniti dignissimos molestias quae.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium fugit dolores autem tempora harum veniam, eos, perferendis rerum quaerat ea, vitae incidunt rem eaque animi culpa deleniti dignissimos molestias quae.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium fugit dolores autem tempora harum veniam, eos, perferendis rerum quaerat ea, vitae incidunt rem eaque animi culpa deleniti dignissimos molestias quae.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium fugit dolores autem tempora harum veniam, eos, perferendis rerum quaerat ea, vitae incidunt rem eaque animi culpa deleniti dignissimos molestias quae.
   </p>
   <p style="background-color:maroon;"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium fugit dolores autem tempora harum veniam, eos, perferendis rerum quaerat ea, vitae incidunt rem eaque animi culpa deleniti dignissimos molestias quae. </p>
   <p style="background-color:black;"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium fugit dolores autem tempora harum veniam, eos, perferendis rerum quaerat ea, vitae incidunt rem eaque animi culpa deleniti dignissimos molestias quae. </p>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**You should save all the code in a html file or view the snippet in Full Page mode.**

**EDIT** If you run the following snippet this is what you will get into the console entering into the green area from the top **only once**.

```
mouse enter 
mouse leave
mouse enter
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 
 <style type="text/css">
  *{margin:0; padding:0;}
  #sidebar {width: 200px; height:400px; background:green; position:relative;}
  .element {width: 100%; height:100%;}
 </style>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.element').on('mouseleave', function(){
    console.log('mouse leave');
   });

   $('.element').on('mouseenter', function(){
    console.log('mouse enter');
   });
  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="sidebar">
  <div class="element">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam dolore adipisci minima deserunt, provident ex distinctio corporis quam ipsam harum ea omnis, officiis libero voluptatum nobis accusantium. Ducimus, sequi, deleniti.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Since this thing seems to happen only in chrome I added `google-chrome` tag to the question.

Video showing the issue : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-eYll72UzMteFZWM1hjeFd1ZFk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Your snippet is working fine for me in Chrome and Safari.

Comment: I think what the OP means is that you see an extra `mouseleave` event being triggered in Chrome when you enter the element from the top and it's flush with the browser UI at the top. To see this, click Full page on the example.

Comment: I created a video to show this. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-eYll72UzMteFZWM1hjeFd1ZFk/edit?usp=sharing . Sorry about the quality. In the video you can see that If I `mouse enter` to the yellow part the `mouse leave` is not logged but if I `mouse enter` from top, the event is logged.

Comment: I feel like the refreshing is irrelevant to the behavior in Chrome. Also, this seems to happen when the console is overlapping the area as well. I'm guessing this is a bug in Chrome. Interestingly, if you add a margin to the `div`,  it'll solve the problem, but only as long as they move the mouse slow enough for the browser to detect that it's entered the margin.

Comment: I was thinking that is a problem with CSS but I can't see what is wrong.(if there's something)

Answer (score 0):

your code work fine and so with native version.

```js
var elmn = document.getElementsByClassName("element");

for (var i=0; i<elmn.length; i++){
  elmn[i].onmouseleave = function(){
    console.log("mouse leave")
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css">
 <style type="text/css">
  * { margin:0; padding:0; }
  html,body{ height:100%; }
  #sidebar{ position: relative; width:200px; height:400px; background:green; overflow: hidden;}
  .elementToScroll { float:left; width:100%; }
 </style>


</head>
<body>
 <div id="sidebar">
  <div class="element">
   <p style="background-color:red;"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium fugit dolores autem tempora harum veniam, eos, perferendis rerum quaerat ea, vitae incidunt rem eaque animi culpa deleniti dignissimos molestias quae. </p>
   <p style="background-color:yellow;"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium fugit dolores autem tempora harum veniam, eos, perferendis rerum quaerat ea, vitae incidunt rem eaque animi culpa deleniti dignissimos molestias quae. </p>
   <p style="background-color:orange;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium fugit dolores autem tempora harum veniam, eos, perferendis rerum quaerat ea, vitae incidunt rem eaque animi culpa deleniti dignissimos molestias quae.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium fugit dolores autem tempora harum veniam, eos, perferendis rerum quaerat ea, vitae incidunt rem eaque animi culpa deleniti dignissimos molestias quae.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium fugit dolores autem tempora harum veniam, eos, perferendis rerum quaerat ea, vitae incidunt rem eaque animi culpa deleniti dignissimos molestias quae.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium fugit dolores autem tempora harum veniam, eos, perferendis rerum quaerat ea, vitae incidunt rem eaque animi culpa deleniti dignissimos molestias quae.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium fugit dolores autem tempora harum veniam, eos, perferendis rerum quaerat ea, vitae incidunt rem eaque animi culpa deleniti dignissimos molestias quae.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium fugit dolores autem tempora harum veniam, eos, perferendis rerum quaerat ea, vitae incidunt rem eaque animi culpa deleniti dignissimos molestias quae.
   </p>
   <p style="background-color:maroon;"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium fugit dolores autem tempora harum veniam, eos, perferendis rerum quaerat ea, vitae incidunt rem eaque animi culpa deleniti dignissimos molestias quae. </p>
   <p style="background-color:black;"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium fugit dolores autem tempora harum veniam, eos, perferendis rerum quaerat ea, vitae incidunt rem eaque animi culpa deleniti dignissimos molestias quae. </p>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Has the same problem when I tested it.

Comment: Yes. Has the same problem. For the readability of the question can you fold your answer ?